# Bootstrap 5 navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I would like my navigation bar to have a black background along its entire length like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNkqy.png
I don't want to move my links in there, or my logo so that it stays in place, but just set a background on its length

Second SASS compilation problem : I apply a new color to it (I don't want its gray : I define #141414 like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvTru.png To tell it that I don't want gray-900 but #141414 however it compiles properly, but doesn't change my color how to do if it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Kurium Client</title>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="container bg-dark">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="logo.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="200" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top">
                <span class="hidden">Kurium Client</span>
              </a>
            <button 
                class="navbar-toggler" 
                type="button" 
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu" 
                aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu" 
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
            
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Forums</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Purchase</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                

            </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Learn more</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Buy Now</a>
      </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look using your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where that background color is being set. It seems to be being set by bootstrap with a !important.

Comment: It's defined on the bodysuit but I don't think it's logical so if I define it logically it's going to put the whole bodysuit in a black background and that's not really what I want since in this bodysuit I'm going to put other things that I don't necessarily want in a black background https://i.imgur.com/XQbj2v7.png

Answer (score 1):

First: You are using bootstrap.css from a contend delivery network. You haven't referenced your own custom css. So you won't see you changes.

But, instead of replacing a color variable you should better add another color to the theme colors.

Bootstrap internally iterates over all colors in this map and generates the corresponding component variants like navbar-dark, navbar-primary etc.

According to
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#add-to-map

You could define your custom color within a map

```
// Create your own map
$custom-colors: (
   "customgray": #141414
 );
```

And then merge your custom color map with the $theme-colors map like

```
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);
```

But be aware that you cannot just import the whole bootstrap. You will have to import all parts on their own.

// Required

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Consider putting these lines wihtin a _custom.scss in your project
// and importing it here
$custom-colors: (
   "customgray": #141414
 );

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

// Optional
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
...
```

This way you can then use

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-customgray">
```

Please do not use !important, because !important is a good indicator that it is important for the "developer" to leave the project.

You can always specialize (in terms of overwriting) your CSS by adding classes and writing new rules instead of using important

Comment: the modifications for example for the color that I want to define instead of gray I say in style.scss what I want instead, and in index.css I do: https://i.imgur.com/KIW26Tu.png no? 

For the continuation I will test thank you for the explanations I confess that I do not understand everything for the moment but I will deepen by researching beside

Comment: I really recommend reading the section "Customize" in the Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/

Comment: I imported my style.css, I recompiled my sass like this: https://i.imgur.com/1QOR7uz.png but I still don't see any change on the color